# How to make images fill table cells while keeping aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

What I'm trying to do is fill table cells with random sized images, but I want the cell to keep a height of 200px, the width must be automatically adjusted to fill the whole table width, that is `td{width: 100%; height: 200px;}`. And the images should fit inside the cells in a manner that they fill the whole cell without distortion, they can be cropped if needed.

I was looking for a solution on the forums and found that I should set the size of my table cell to whatever dimensions I want, and then set the image inside it to `img{with: 100%; height: auto;}` It makes sense to me but unfortunately it doesn't work. I put a JSFiddle together to show what is happening: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alekrabbe/8nthmrhu/)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want the table cells to be filled using your method, you have to force the cell to have the same aspect ratio as the image: and this is extremely difficult since HTML table cell dimensions are adjusted based on content. Your best bet is to assign a background image with the size set to `cover`. But this wouldn't work for your use case since you are displaying a grid of images of varying aspect ratios: your only solution would likely to be a JS-based one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either force the table cells to have the same ratio as the image (@Terry) or use the image as a background for the cell.

CSS:

```
td {
    background-image: url('path-to-image');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1myu255g/
Please forgive me for not using all images, but I am sure you got the point :).